# Minimum date of the transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My requirement

[image]

How to fetch the minimum transaction date that transacts after 'withdrawal'?

I just want the output of transactiondate '2/11/2020'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` and filtering and aggregation:

```
select account, min(tdate)
from (select t.*,
             lag(type) over (partition by account order by tdate) as prev_type
      from t
     ) t
where prev_type = 'Withdrawal'
group by account;
```